# Parsing partstat from an .ics file using icalendar (Python)

Tags: python, icalendar

Python newbie here. I am using an .ics file from Google Calendar and would like to parse the participation status of each event attendee ('PARTSTAT') using icalendar and add it to a DataFrame. Here are two examples of what an attendee component looks like in the file:

```
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=email1@domain.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:email1@domain.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=email2@domain.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:email2@domain.com
```

I was able to parse several components successfully, but since PARTSTAT is a subcomponent of ATTENDEE, I cannot figure out what I need to change to extract it. Below is my code, including 4 different attempts to parse PARTSTAT along with the results/error messages I got (muted). See below:

```
g = open(icsfile, 'rb')
gcal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())

for event in gcal.walk('vevent'):
    e = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['uid', 'start', 'end', 'summary', 'attendee', 'partstat','description'])
    e.uid = [event.get('uid')]
    e.start = [event.decoded('dtstart')]
    e.end = [event.decoded('dtend')]
    e.summary = [event.get('summary')]
    e.attendee = [event.get('attendee')]
    
    #e.partstat = event.get('partstat')  #results in partstat of "None" for each e
    
    #e.partstat = event.get('attendee').params['partstat']  #AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'params'
    
    #e.partstat = event['attendee'].get('partstat') #AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
    
    #e.partstat = event['attendee'].params['partstat'] #AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'params'
    
    allevents = allevents.append(e, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example on how to get the partstat param:

```
vcal = Calendar.from_ical("...some ical content...")
vevent = vcal.walk("VEVENT")[0]
attendee = vevent.get("ATTENDEE")
partstat = attendee.params['PARTSTAT']
```

if you have more than 1 attendee when you do

```
attendee = vevent.get("ATTENDEE")
```

attendee while containt a list, so

```
partstart = attendee[0].params['PARTSTAT']
```

where 0 is an index (you can also use a for)